# Move child of Stack at the bottom of the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to move the Container which is 2nd child of stack and wrapped around Padding to be at the bottom of the screen instead of Top.

```
 body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: itemData.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                 itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){ 
                   return Text(data[index].name);
 }

                     ),

          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                color: Colors.cyan
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              height: 60,

            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your second child with `Align`:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          color: Colors.cyan),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      height: 60,
    ),
  ),
)
```

But note that this will cover your list when it becomes big. Unless this is what you want you can use a Column instead of a Stack.

Comment: @ Sami Haddad, Hey this worked. Earlier I was using align property of Container and got failed miserably. Thanks

Comment: Actually I'm only showing this container only after it satisfies certain conditions. So this Worked,.

Answer (score 1):

To position widgets inside a stack you can use the `Positioned` widget. You can pass it left right top and bottom offsets to position whereever you like within the Stack.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=EgtPleVwxBQ

Comment: But this way, position of the container will differ for mobile devices of different size.

Comment: @PraveenGupta Well, you would have to make it dynamic using MediaQuery.of(context). But you ll have to do that anyways with any solution